# Applications written by Yesod sometimes stop responding

Tags: haskell, web, yesod

Applications written by Yesod sometimes stop responding

I write a proprietary web application with Yesod with [ncaq/try-pandoc-with-file: try pandoc! with file](https://github.com/ncaq/try-pandoc-with-file).
I can not publish proprietary application code.

I am troubled that these applications sometimes stop responding.
Especially, proprietary applications will not respond at about once a day cycle.

The process is still running, it is not finished, no error is seen even if you look at the log with journalctl, so I do not know the cause at all.

I confirm that I have fallen by the health check of Route 53 now and restart it every time I fall.

I am very embarrassed.

Does anyone know the solution, or how to debug?

Application deployment is done by starting application from stack from systemd and applying reverse proxy with nginx.

Because I am not good at English, this sentence is subject to google translation.The original text is also shown below.

---

Yesodで書いたアプリケーションが時々応答しなくなる

私は[ncaq/try-pandoc-with-file: try pandoc! with file](https://github.com/ncaq/try-pandoc-with-file)と,プロプライエタリのwebアプリケーションをYesodで書いています.
プロプライエタリのアプリケーションのコードは公開できません.ごめんなさい.

これらのアプリケーションが時々応答しなくなることに困っています.
特に,プロプライエタリのアプリケーションの方は1日に1回程度の周期で応答しなくなります.

プロセスは動いたままで,終了しているわけでもなく,journalctlでログを見てもエラーが出てないので,原因が全然わかりません.

現在Route53のヘルスチェックで落ちたことを確認して,落ちるたびに再起動をしています.

とても困っています.

どなたか,解決方法,もしくはデバッグする方法を知らないでしょうか?

アプリケーションのデプロイは,systemdからstackでアプリケーションを起動して,nginxでリバースプロキシをかけるという方法で行っています.

私は英語が得意ではないため,この文章はgoogle翻訳にかけられます.原文を下に併記します.

Comment: "I can not publish proprietary application code" - this does not relieve you of the requirement of creating a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without the code producing this problem, it is entirely impossible for anybody here to identify the cause (making the question off-topic).

Comment: It also happens with [ncaq/try-pandoc-with-file: try pandoc! With file](https://github.com/ncaq/try-pandoc-with-file), but is not it?